# Is there any mapping table between windows code and java charset?

Tags: java, codepages

Is there any mapping table between windows code and java charset?

[Java Charset list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/intl/encoding.doc.html)

[Windows Code page list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756(v=vs.85).aspx)

Why I want that:
  I have to read and analyse a binary file which contains part:

```
0x00 word codepage like 1252, 936, 65001 I knew, and also 50222 I did not know.
0x02 word string length
0x04 bytes null-terminated string 
...more strings...
```

I wrote the code:

```
int codepage = read16(inputStream);
int length = read16(inputStream);
byte[] bytes = new byte[length];
inputStream.read(bytes, 0, length);
String str = new String(bytes, getCharsetFromCodepage(codepage));
```

and getCharsetFromCodepage is what I want.

Comment: There is similar thing in javascript https://github.com/czhj/codepage-encoding/blob/master/codepages.json

Comment: Just from looking at the list, it looks like converting the canonical `java.nio` name to lower case will give you the .net name.

Comment: Can't you map the code pages on a string, using "identifiers" is not a really portable way to talk between different languages

Comment: Default code page of locale https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa912040.aspx